# What does the export tag mean?

Tags: catkin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am not sure what the export tag (and what you put inside) imply.

For instance :

```
<name>my_pkg</name>
...
<export>
    <gazebo_ros gazebo_model_path="${prefix}/models"/>
</export>
```

Is it some kind of argument that is passed to gazebo_ros, each time gazebo_ros is called from my_pkg ? For instance, like this :

(example.launch, from my_pkg:)

```
<launch>
    <node name="node" pkg="gazebo_ros" type="script.sh" />
</launch>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/251862/what-does-the-export-tag-mean?/) by [kaldo](https://answers.ros.org/users/29026/kaldo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2017-01-13

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Is it some kind of argument that is passed to gazebo_ros, each time gazebo_ros is called from my_pkg ?

Almost, but no (at least not directly).

From [REP-140: Package Manifest Format Two Specification - Data Representation - export](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0140.html#export):

> This tag serves as a container for additional information various packages and subsystems need to embed. To avoid potential collisions, an export tag should have the same name as the package which is meant to process it. The content of that tag is up to the package to define and use.

It basically allows packages to provide extra or required information to packages they "extend" (and here I use that term to mean: for which they provide additional functionality, artefacts, anything, beyond the restricted OOP definition). In this case, Gazebo will know how to use the information you put in the `gazebo_ros` child element (but it has to go and fetch that information *itself* (via `rospkg` fi), that is why I wrote "not directly").

You can see the `gazebo_ros_paths_plugin` plugin doing that [here](https://github.com/ros-simulation/gazebo_ros_pkgs/blob/4225bf4dd6bbc599679c487abc51947b841c94d0/gazebo_ros/src/gazebo_ros_paths_plugin.cpp#L82-L90).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-01-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kaldo](https://answers.ros.org/users/29026/kaldo/) on 2017-01-13**:
It's much clearer now, thanks!